# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key with get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas

I want to data cleaning for google play store app dataset.

```
df['Type'] = pd.get_dummies(df['Type'])
```

But i get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20080/2858164690.py in <module>
      1 # Type encoding
----> 2 df['Type'] = pd.get_dummies(df['Type'])

D:\Anaconda\Program Files\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3600             self._setitem_array(key, value)
   3601         elif isinstance(value, DataFrame):
-> 3602             self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)
   3603         elif (
   3604             is_list_like(value)

D:\Anaconda\Program Files\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item_frame_value(self, key, value)
   3727             len_cols = 1 if is_scalar(cols) else len(cols)
   3728             if len_cols != len(value.columns):
-> 3729                 raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
   3730 
   3731             # align right-hand-side columns if self.columns

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Comment: `get_dummies` is going to return `n` columns based on the number of columns needed to dummies encode the column. You're assigning back to `df['Type']` which is `1` column. Which is the issue. Multiple columns will not fit into a single column. It's possible you're looking for `df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Type'])`